# 100% Cpu Utilization

Tags: windows-8.1, cpu, cpu-usage

the 100% cpu load is very annoying and make the device run hotter weather its a desktop or laptop also the programs crashes with weird bug . i have a Lenovo laptop G500 with windows 8.1 x64 bit enterprise edition I noticed that when cpu load 100% i open the task manager i see that the program use the cpu is background the program I don't interact with it directly . example when i open Photoshop and render s 4k image it's naturally cpu reach 100% but when the program in the background and use a lot of processing power that's weird.

[image: screenshot]

the link provide my task manger under 100% cpu usage adobe acrobat use 25% and adobe open minimize it in the taskbar ? when i end the adobe acrobat process through task manager the cpu drop down a little bit and **after that return to 100% again because jumped to other program in the background ?**
so I explained deeply and clearly i want complete fix to my annoying problem :[

Comment: That's how it typically works with concurrent processes.

Comment: what do you mean by concurrent processes ?

Comment: Concurrent process are processes running simultaneously. When one stops other will increase its usage of resources. Resources are finite and must be divided among all the concurrent processes. 100% load is normal and expected whenever any software capable of using all the available resources is running. It is not normal to have such load all the time if no foreground and background processes that typically call for such resources aren't running but otherwise it's perfectly normal.  Overheating, if that's a problem, is more likely related with cooling not working as it should, not CPU load.

Comment: A Lenovo G500 is an **entry-level business laptop**. It wasn't designed for demanding software workload (photo/video editing and rendering, games, etc.) and Windows 8.x is more resource intensive than anything before or after (Windows 10) which adds to the problem. I think you need to have **realist expectations**. Upgrading Windows is likely to improve performance but at the end of the day it's a laptop for web-browsing, Office and media consumption only, by definition. That should be expected across all its configurations (Celeron, i3 or i5). End of story.

Comment: Please break your question up into paragraphs

Comment: yes Lenovo G-500 with core i3 and also old since 2013 but i have a question is there a virus or Trojan make cpu run at 100% ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for a computer to over-heat, although if your CPU is recent
enough, then it should throttle itself down in such case.

Things you can try :

- Assure that all air passages are clean
- If your environment is dusty, cleaning the interior might help
- A cooling pad may improve the situation
- Verify the thermal paste of the CPU
- Replace the CPU cooling fan by a better one
- Windows : In
  *Control Panel > Power options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings*,
  expand "Processor power management" and set "Maximum processor state" to 98% for
  both Battery and Plugged-in (this shouldn't change the performance noticeably)
- Last option: See a repairman.

Comment: my problem is cpu load at 100%

Comment: If you have programs that are running at full speed, what's wrong with 100% CPU? Or are these programs not supposed to be using the CPU?

Comment: @harrymc This is one of those cases of a Citroen C1 owner pushing it like a BMW M series and then complaining the engine is constantly high-revving.

Comment: Guys there a virus or Trojan that make cpu run at 100% . if it yes i will run virus scan

Comment: If you think there is no reason for these programs to use that much CPU, run deep virus scans using several well-known antivirus products (they don't all check for the same things).