# Laptop heating up during downloads or watching movies

Tags: cpu, fan, overheating

Device: Ideapad Gaming 3-15IMH05 Laptop - Type 81Y4

I bought this laptop over a month ago. Usually when I'm working with it I'm using headphones so I don't hear anything.

When im not playing with it but watching movie or downloading, the system heats up fast and the fan starts working very hard, its sound like an airplane.

What could be the cause?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Lenovo lists 2 different models of this laptop, a Core-i5 and a Core-i7. That means there are many possible configurations available. Can you please add to the question your Windows version, the amount of RAM, the drive size and type (HDD/SSD/NVMe) and other basic info like that? Does it heat up when you're streaming a movie, or also when you're playing one from an internal drive?

Comment: Processortype Tooltip
Intel Core i7
Processor number Tooltip
i7-10750H (6 cores)

Comment: Internal memory 
16 GB

Comment: Total storage capacity Tooltip
1256 GB
Type of storage
HDD and SSD
Storage capacity SSD
256 GB
HDD storage capacity
1000 GB
Storage capacity Flash
0
Hard drive speed Tooltip
5400 RPM

Comment: it gets headted even when im not doing anything, sometimes i leave the laptop for as few min (on desktop nothing is open) then i come back i can hear the sound of the fan inside the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

My best advice is to return the laptop to the vendor and get reimbursement,
as this behavior is not correct. If return is not possible, ask for
Support and repairs, as something is wrong with this laptop.

For advice relating to overheating laptops, see the post
[100% Cpu Utilization](https://superuser.com/questions/1644019/100-cpu-utilization).